# Как взаимодействовать с bootstrap и моими стилями в React?

Tags: reactjs

Например у меня есть такой код компонента

```
<div className="d-flex theme-panel">
   ...
</div>
```

`.d-flex` - это класс bootstrap

`.theme-block` - это мой класс с описанием цвета блока для цветовой схемы

Так вот в чем вопрос:

У меня на данный момент в index.js импортируются 2 css файла, bootstrap.css и style.css

Для безболезненного изменения цветовой схемы я хочу переписать код компонента так:

```
<div className={myStyle.themePanel}>  // Куда здесь запихать .d-flex?
   ...
</div>
```

С моими стилями все понятно, импортирую и юзаю, а вот как быть с глобальными стилями bootstrap? Как их использовать совместно с css-modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку `myStyle.themePanel` также является `string`:

```
<div className={`d-flex ${myStyle.themePanel}`}>
   ...
</div>
```

[Шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)